# How to send BLE commands using CoreBluetooth?

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I want to connect to ohaus scale using ohaus bluetooth interface:

https://dmx.ohaus.com/WorkArea/showcontent.aspx?id=4294974224

I succeeded to connect and receive the CBCharacteristic with uuid 2456e1b9-26e2-8f83-e744-f34f01e9d703.

I want to get the weight of the scale. Here is what I do:

```
//send command to the scale
let data = "IP"
let valueString = (data as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
self.scalePeripheral.writeValue(valueString!, for: scaleCharchteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
```

I should expect to receive the scale weight with the delegate function:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic,error: Error?){
    guard 
        let characteristicValue = characteristic.value,
        let characteristicASCIIValue = NSString(data: characteristicValue, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    else {
        return
    }
    print("\((characteristicASCIIValue as String))")
}
```

But I receive empty value.

Also I don't receive any data to `peripheralDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic`.

What may be the problem?

Here is the reference of the bluetooth commands:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just access `characteristic.value` you need to either:

- Perform a [`readValue(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518759-readvalue) of the characteristic and wait for a callback to [`peripheral(_:didUpdateValueFor:error)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518708-peripheral) or
- Enable characteristic notifications via [`setNotifyValue(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518949-setnotifyvalue)

Not all characteristics support notifications, but if it is supported, it is the best approach to use, rather than polling.

Since it appears that your device is emulating a serial port over GATT, it is quite likely that notifications are supported (Check the `properties` of your characteristic for `notify` or `indicate` support).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do use setNotifyValue . when I use the read value I get : "Reading is not permitted" I don't know what's may be the problem .

Comment: The characteristic probably doesn't support read, just notify; check it's properties.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do use setNotifyValue, and I do receive the weight from the scale device, however I receive it only when I click on print button on the scale device. what I need to do , is to send the "print" command to the device via bluetooth . I am unable to send the print command . thanks

Comment: It doesn't say it in the manual, but I would try sending `"IP\r\n"`

Comment: now it's working, what does the \r\n do ? Thank you very much,

Comment: It sends carriage return and new line characters.